# How to answer when the solution was published/proven a century ago?

Tags: discussion

Similar to "chestnuts" for riddles, sometimes math puzzles are based on things that have already been done. For example, a recent magic-square question has an answer that is very easily searchable, with a solution that goes back a bit over a century.

Do I simply copy/paste the solution and explain it a bit (along with attribution, of course)? Should I wait a while and let people puzzle it over instead? By "easily searchable" I mean it's within the top few hits on Google for somewhat obvious search terms, so I don't expect it will be long before *someone* finds and/or answers it.

Comment: This is a good question that I also have. I think maybe it is a good idea to let people who don't know the puzzle try it for some time. But even if I refrain from posting, some other user who knows it will post the solution.

Answer (score 10):

I think, in general, there is nothing wrong with copying the solution from elsewhere and citing your source. Having good solutions posted as answers to a puzzle is helpful to people who want to understand the puzzle better, no matter where that solution came from. As long as your answer is a good reference for future puzzle enthusiasts who want to understand more about the puzzle, then it is a good answer in my mind.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of "no googling". If I happen to know the answer already then should I sabotage my write-up because I don't recall the full details I need to cite the original work?